# How to use if statement depending on UIView background color

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to use an `if statement` depending on the background color of the view controller.

```
if view.backgroundColor = .red {

}
```

This is not working. It gives me the error:

> Value of type 'UIColor?' has no member 'red'

I just want the `if statement` depending on the programmatically set background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `==` when comparing; `=` is the assignment operator

```
if view.backgroundColor == .red {

}
```